# Google Maps - How do I Add Info Window to Marker?

Tags: apex, google-map, google

I am developing a page where a user can press a button on an account and a map will display with markers created for each nearby account.

I have been able to create the markers for each account, however I cannot find a way to create an infowindow for each marker with the account's information. The infowindow I created shows the same information for every marker.

I created the mapping utility as a component, the code for that follows:

```
<apex:component controller="accountMapController">
    <apex:attribute name="addList" type="String" assignTo="{!addString}" description="Account: Addresses"/>
    <apex:attribute name="height" type="Integer" assignTo="{!mapHeight}" description="Map height in pixels"/>
    <apex:attribute name="width" type="Integer" assignTo="{!mapWidth}" description="Map width in pixels"/>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                mapTypeControl: true
            }
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( {
                content: "hello"
            } );
            var add = "{!addString}";
            var adds = add.split("+");
            for (var i = 0; i < adds.length; i++){
                geocoder.geocode( {address: adds[i]}, function(results, status) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker( {
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        labelContent: "label",
                        map: map,
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map,marker);
                        var place = marker.getPlace();
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        function resizeIframe() {
            var me = window.name;
            if (me) {
                var iframes = parent.document.getElementsByName(me);
                if (iframes && iframes.length == 1) {
                    height = document.body.offsetHeight;
                    iframes[0].style.height = height + "px";
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
        <style>
            #map {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 12px;
                line-height: normal !important;
                height: {!mapHeight}px;
                width: {!mapWidth}px;
                background: transparent;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div> 
    </body>
</apex:component>
```

Any ideas how I can change the "content: 'hello'" to cycle through a list of descriptions, similar to how it cycles through the adds to create markers?

Comment: If you are going to stick with the Javascript route, you should ask this question on Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: Ryan, that doesn't appear to be related to salesforce ? Please understand that this site is dedicated to questions specifically around salesforce technologies.

Comment: I apologize I'll move it over to Stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

FYI there are standard [map](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_map.htm) and [map marker](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_mapMarker.htm) components now for VisualForce. I believe with the `mapMarker` component what you want is fairly straightforward. You would just put your content inside the tag.

```
<apex:map center="{!mapCenter}">
    <apex:mapMarker title="Marker 1" position="{!position1}">
        Content
    </apex:mapMarker>
</apex:map>
```

I still have to test to verify.

**UPDATE**

You cannot have child content inside the `mapMarker` tag. I know I saw someone do this but I have to keep hunting for a link. It is [supposed to be possible](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_vf_maps_enhancements_info_windows.htm) in Summer 15.